# Format string into HTML <li> elements

Tags: jquery, arrays

How could I ***split*** string or get invidual words out of string. I'm trying get output like this whit `<li></li>` elements:

```
-Ryan Gosling
-Emma Stone 
-Amiée Conn 
-Terry Walters
```

But it keeps displaying like this in ***single row***: Ryan Gosling, Emma Stone, Amiée Conn, Terry Walters,

> **Fiddle JS code:** https://jsfiddle.net/ysch9hfg/5/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function () {
        $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + (filmi.Movies[0].Actors) + '</li>')
          });
    });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ysch9hfg/8/ please check the updated fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/9bwwuobw/

```
$("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").append(
    '<li class="list-group-item">' + 
    (filmi.Movies[0].Actors.split(', ').join(
         '</li><li class="list-group-item">'
     ) + '</li>'
 )});
```

Comment: Exacly what I was trying to achieve. +1

Comment: A bit naughty. It works, but you might want to use an each instead to allow processing of each actor

Answer (score 0):

Do it using the split function.Then iterate over each loop:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function () {

  var res = filmi.Movies[0].Actors.split(", ");

  $(res).each(function(key,value){


   $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + value + '</li>')
      });
  })

});
```

[JS Fiddle Working Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ysch9hfg/9/)

Comment: You need to remove the space too

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code

[fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ysch9hfg/8/)

```
$((filmi.Movies[0].Actors).split(',')).each(function(){
        $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").append('<li class="list-group-item">' +this + '</li>'); 
    });
```

Comment: You want to remove the space too

Answer (score 0):

Although you can split and join LI, this is more in the spirit of jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
     $.each(filmi.Movies[0].Actors.split(", "),function(_,actor) {
      // here you can process actor - add image etc
      $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush")
        .append('<li class="list-group-item">' + actor + '</li>');
     });
  });
});

const filmi = {
  "Movies": [{
    "Title": "La La Land",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "25 Dec 2016",
    "Runtime": "128 min",
    "Genre": "Comedy, Drama, Music",
    "Director": "Damien Chazelle",
    "Writer": "Damien Chazelle",
    "Actors": "Ryan Gosling, Emma Stone, Amiée Conn, Terry Walters",
    "Plot": "A jazz pianist falls for an aspiring actress in Los Angeles.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA, Hong Kong",
    "Awards": "Won 6 Oscars. Another 184 wins & 224 nominations.",
    "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzUzNDM2NzM2MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTM3NTg4OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings": [{
        "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
        "Value": "8.3/10"
      },
      {
        "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
        "Value": "93%"
      },
      {
        "Source": "Metacritic",
        "Value": "93/100"
      }
    ],
    "Metascore": "93",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    "imdbVotes": "232,825",
    "imdbID": "tt3783958",
    "Type": "movie",
    "DVD": "25 Apr 2017",
    "BoxOffice": "$150,459,658.00",
    "Production": "Liongate Films",
    "Website": "http://www.lalaland.movie/",
    "Response": "True"
  }]
}
```

```css
.container ul:nth-child(1) li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<h1>Actors</h1>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <ul class="list-group"></ul>
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block">Display</button>
      <br/>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="" />
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>
        <div class="card-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not outputting them with a loop. You need to put it into a for loop or something and incrementing your array key.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var arr = filmi.Movies[0].Actors.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
      $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + (arr[i]) + '</li>');
    }
  });

});


const filmi = {
  "Movies": [{
    "Title": "La La Land",
    "Year": "2016",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "25 Dec 2016",
    "Runtime": "128 min",
    "Genre": "Comedy, Drama, Music",
    "Director": "Damien Chazelle",
    "Writer": "Damien Chazelle",
    "Actors": "Ryan Gosling, Emma Stone, Amiée Conn, Terry Walters",
    "Plot": "A jazz pianist falls for an aspiring actress in Los Angeles.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA, Hong Kong",
    "Awards": "Won 6 Oscars. Another 184 wins & 224 nominations.",
    "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzUzNDM2NzM2MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTM3NTg4OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings": [{
        "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
        "Value": "8.3/10"
      },
      {
        "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
        "Value": "93%"
      },
      {
        "Source": "Metacritic",
        "Value": "93/100"
      }
    ],
    "Metascore": "93",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    "imdbVotes": "232,825",
    "imdbID": "tt3783958",
    "Type": "movie",
    "DVD": "25 Apr 2017",
    "BoxOffice": "$150,459,658.00",
    "Production": "Liongate Films",
    "Website": "http://www.lalaland.movie/",
    "Response": "True"
  }]
}
```

```css
.container ul:nth-child(1) li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929877/format-string-into-html-li-elements#ootstrap.min.css" />


<h1>Actors</h1>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <ul class="list-group"></ul>
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block">Display</button>
      <br/>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="" />
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>
        <div class="card-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this? Use the split function to split the actors names. Then loop top append a li.

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var actors = filmi.Movies[0].Actors.split(',');
    $(actors).each(function(index){
        $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + actors[index] + '</li>');
    })  
 });
```